# UIButton inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I would like to use a scroll view inside my app.I will explain the situation:
Mine is a recipe app.I would like to show all the recipe images inside a scroll view and  when i click an image inside the scroll view ,the corresponding ingredients and preparations has to be shown .I saw many tutorials using image view inside the uiscrollview,thought of replacing image view with button.But all those tutorials are so complicated .Can any one refer me a simple example.
[image]
This my apps seccond page.when i click a particular recipe in first page its image and ingredients and preparation is shown.But i would like to show all the images in uiscrollview,and when i click a particular image,corresponding ingredients and preparations has to be shown

Comment: Why dont you use tableview?

Comment: [myScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 60)];

[myScrollView addSubview:myButton];
CGRect buttonLocation = CGRectMake(25, 20, 80, 30);
[myButton setFrame:buttonLocation];

Comment: Yea table view is a better solution. If you are working on recipies and stuff try this https://github.com/YuxinYang/ios-5-recipe-sample

Comment: @Mak:Sorry the layout given for me is like that.And i am using tableviews inside  a popoverview for displaying ingredients and preparations

Comment: What is your actual requirement and could you paste an image of your requirement

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919761/adding-a-uibutton-to-uiscrollview

Comment: @Manohar:i have updated my question

Comment: Got the solution to this @haritha

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view I think that if you would use a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView` (or the corespondent controllers: `UITableViewController` and `UICollectionViewController`) you would achieve grater results than trying to add buttons with images inside a scroll view.

[UITableView Tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/) and [UICollectionView Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/)

Also you can go and watch the Apple's WWDC videos

I hope this is helpful for you, 
Cheeers

Answer (score 0):

Place UIscrollview In View Xib, then add UIButtons Inside UIScrollview , set buttons actions by hooking action type touch up inside in button pressed add subview on UIView and Show details of Recipe.[self.view addSubView:RecipeDetailView]; here recipe detail view subview where you load reciepe info on button pressed.